# Custom Validator Angular dependency injection

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on custom Validator on Angular/ typescript. This is my class:

```
export class Validator {
    constructor(private sharedDocument: SharedDocument) { }

    static amountIsValid(control: FormControl): any {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(Number.parseInt(control.value), "control.value");
                if (Number.parseInt(control.value) >= this.sharedDocument.getNewRestToPay()) {
                    resolve({
                        "error !": true
                    });
                }
                else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            }, 50);
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, i try to call getNewRestToPay() method from another component by DI.
but this component can be only static. it show me an error:
Property 'sharedDocument' does not exist on type 'Validator'.

If i use a static component i need to change the methode on the component side to be a static method. In this case, i can't return my proprety that i need.

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedDocument {
//some code
getNewRestToPay() :any{
        return this.restCaisse;
    }
}
```

how i can resolve this problem ?

Comment: Why not pass `sharedDocument: SharedDocument` as a parameter to `amountIsValid`?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to guess that this is because your Validator is never instantiated and therefore DI is never made available.

You can also create Dependency Injections inline (not through the constructor) - this may solve your problem.

import the `Reflective Injector`

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
```

Change your method like so

```
    static amountIsValid(control: FormControl): any {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(Number.parseInt(control.value), "control.value");
                    if (Number.parseInt(control.value) >= 
                        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([SharedDocument]);
                        let sharedDocument = injector.get(SharedDocument);
                        sharedDocument.getNewRestToPay()) {
                        resolve({
                            "error !": true
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve(null);
                    }
                }, 50);
            });
        }
```

Edit: But like another commenter has mentioned - do you really need to use DI for this scenario? Can you not simply pass a SharedDocument instance into your `amountIsValid` method?